# Put the side bar component inside a div

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have a component named app-side-menu and I want to put this component inside of blue rectangle occupying full height of blue div [image]
If you notice, the menu is exceeding the lower limits of the blue div, and when I scroll down de menu goes with the scroll

app.component.html

```
<div class="top-menu" style="border:1px solid red;height: 60px;">  

    <app-top-menu></app-top-menu>

</div>
<div class="wrapper"style="border:5px solid green">

    <div class="left-menu" style="border:3px solid blue">

       <app-side-menu></app-side-menu> 

    </div>

    <div class="main-content">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>

    </div>
</div>
```

app.component.css

```
.top-menu{
    padding: 0%;
    margin: 0px;


}

.main-content{
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid pink;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 86%


}

.wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%
}

.left-menu{
    position: relative;
   float: left;
   width: 14%;
   height: 100%;

}
```

side-menu.css

```
[data-component='sidebar'] .first-menu {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #292a2c;
  height: 100vw;
  width: 75px;
  top: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking. please elaborate

Comment: how is html/css in your <app-side-menu>.Does it have any margins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking. You want to make the dark menu be full height of the blue box but not scroll with the view-port. If so you need to position the component absolute. Positioning fixed will ensure it is always in the view-port.

Keep the parent or .left-menu positioned relative and then change your component to.

```
[data-component='sidebar'] .first-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px; // 0 if you want it to start right at the top of left menu
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #292a2c;
  width: 75px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}
```